# prop() doesn't work with some attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following elements on my html page:

```
<ul class="form-tabs">
    <li class="active" data-bind="blah-blah-blah-1">
    <li class="" data-bind="blah-blah-blah-2">
</ul>
```

I need to iterate over `data-bind` properties, so I did the following:

```
$("ul.form-tabs > li").prop('data-bind', function (index, element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

There are two `undefined` in log. [JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/prop) says: *It returns `undefined` for the value of a property that has not been set, or if the matched set has no elements.* But, wait a minute, my `<li>` has `data-bind` property! Also, when i try to use `.prop('class')`, it works perfect giving me `"active"` and `""`.

I said OK and wrote this:

```
$("ul.form-tabs > li").each(function (index, element) {
  console.log(element.prop('data-bind'));
});
```

Now i have this error: `TypeError: element.prop is not a function`.

So, the question is: what am i doing wrong?

P.S. I use jquery 1.10.1 and knockout. Could this be a conflict?

P.P.S. Thanks to everyone, this code works perfect:

```
$("ul.form-tabs > li").each(function (index, element) {
  console.log($(element).attr('data-bind'));
});
```

Comment: Try `$(element).prop()`.

Comment: `.prop()` is supposed to be used for *properties.* `.attr()` would be more appropriate for `data-bind`

Comment: use `.data('bind')` to get data-bind attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difference between "properties" and "attributes". A "property" is something available directly on the DOM node; things like "id", "name", "tagName", etc are properties.

Attributes that the HTML parser doesn't recognize as standard attributes for a particular tag are *not* available as properties on the DOM node. Instead, they have to be accessed via `.setAttribute()` and `.getAttribute()`. In jQuery terms, that means using `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.

The "family" of `data-*` attributes are a little special, because the jQuery `.data()` mechanism will implicitly fetch values from those when the corresponding data key is requested. It will **not**, however, update the attribute values via `setAttribute()`. Whether you need that or not is up to the way your code works. When the attributes involved are intended to be interpreted by another library, then how such updates need to work depends on that library; it may not be possible to approach the problem this way at all, since the other library may not pay attention to the DOM attribute value after it's initially dealt with the element.

Anyway, when using `.data()` to access `data-*` attributes, jQuery expects the keys to look like the portion of the attribute name following the `data-` prefix. For (I guess) convenience, jQuery will treat camel-case versions of data keys as equivalent to dash-separated versions. That is, if the HTML element looks like

```
<div id=x data-some-thing=whatever>
```

then from jQuery you can fetch the value in either of these ways:

```
var withDashes = $("#x").data("some-thing");
var camelCase = $("#x").data("someThing");
```

Another thing to note: sometimes, fetching the value of a DOM node property as the property value instead of the attribute value gets you different results. One important example is the `href` attribute of `<a>` elements or the `action` attribute of a `<form>` tag. The *property* values will (in most browsers, anyway; maybe all) be "normalized" to reflect the actual URL that would be used should the tag be activated. The attribute value, on the other hand, will remain what was originally parsed from the HTML source. That can be important when you've got client-side code imposing its own interpretation on those sorts of attributes.

Comment: Also note Quentin's observation that you're trying to use a DOM node reference as if it were a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you are doing wrong is conflating properties and attributes. There is not always a 1:1 connection between them.

Use `jQueryObject.data('bind')` to read the value of `data-bind` attributes.

The second thing you are doing wrong is expecting that `this` inside a jQuery `each` loop will be a jQuery object. It isn't, it will be a DOM object.

Use `jQuery(this).data('prop')`.

Comment: Do you know whether Knockout will notice an update to one of its guiding attributes like that? *edit* - wait; maybe it was another question today about updating attributes like that; this OP doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data()` instead.

```
$('ul.form-tabs > li').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('bind'));
});
```